# SQL subquery optimization Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, optimization

I don't know much about SQL so I hope my query below could be improved with your knowledge. The fact is my PC can't handle this query, so I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

My query is:

```sql
SELECT 
    v.*, 
    IIF((SELECT COUNT(v2.pk) FROM demo v2 
         WHERE v.place = v2.place 
           AND v.date = v2.date) > 1, "Si", "No")
FROM demo AS v;
```

The point is to flag the records that have another record with the same `place` and the same `date`.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on how your PC can't handle the query. Do you mean to use iif (and not if)? Interesting to see "Si" or "No" written as booleans, didn't know you could change syntax like that.

Comment: With only one clause matters if or iif? "Si" and "No" are the values retorned so I dont know what are u meaning... Anyway, I removed the if and just use the values retorned with count and it's still too hard to execute...

The problem is not my PC HW, maybe acces cant handle this but i cant change it :(

do you think there is a better way to build the query?

Comment: How many records are in "demo"? -- Have you tried the query wizard to find duplicates in Access?

Comment: Actually there are about 45000 records but it will be increased daily... I don't know what is it but i will search about, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a `GROUP BY` query which gives you the count for each combination of `place` and `date` ...

```sql
SELECT v2.place, v2.date, COUNT(*) AS group_count
FROM demo AS v2 
GROUP BY v2.place, v2.date
```

Then you can use it as a subquery which you join back to the `demo` table and add your `IIf` expression to the top-level `SELECT` clause ...

```sql
SELECT
    v.*, IIf(sub.group_count > 1, 'Si', 'No')
FROM
    demo AS v
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT v2.place, v2.date, COUNT(*) AS group_count
        FROM demo AS v2 
        GROUP BY v2.place, v2.date
    ) AS sub
    ON v.place = sub.place AND v.date = sub.date;
```

Regarding performance, you should index both the `place` and `date` fields.  If the `demo` table is really huge, this query may not be blazing fast, but it should be faster than your original version.

I suggest you also replace `v.*` with a list of the fields you want to see.  `v.*` requires 2 steps: first find the field names which correspond to `v.*`; and second, retrieve the data for those fields.  So listing the field names eliminates that first step.  And if you only need to see a subset of the available fields, listing them by name means less data for the db engine to retrieve.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot!!! it is working correctly and quicker than my but there's a problem. Demo table has 45000 records and Query table has only 35000.... In order to fix it I changed INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN and it seems to work but I'm not sure if It can influence to incorrect results in some cases...

Comment: Yes, with INNER JOIN some records are lost... Maybe there are some trash records with place and date null or something like that. Probably is a DB problem and not a query one. Thank you a lot!!

Comment: I understand now.  Thanks.  My suggestion did not anticipate Nulls in either of the join fields.